# How can I pull the order value of a sale from Magento Go?

Tags: price, javascript, sales, magento-go

I am using Mangento Go and after a sale has taken place on the confirmation page I am using a JS code that needs the value of the sale in a variable like $totalvalue.

I am unable to find something in the templates to grab that value and put it into a variable.  ANy ideas on how I can do this? I am new to Magento so very lost.  Please let me know if there is a way.  Thanks!

I found this page: http://go.magento.com/support/kb/entry/name/defining-transactional-variables/

But they are referring to transactional emails but i need this on the sales confirmation page.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Magento Go which will be shut down soon.

Answer (score 1):

The order is not available on the success page. What you can do (at least in CE) is to load it:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($this->getOrderId());
```

then you can get the value via

```
$order->getBaseGrandTotal();  /* or */  $order->getGrandTotal();
```